# Download YouTube music as MP3

Tags: windows, gratis, youtube, mp3, media-converter

I need software that can download YouTube tracks as MP3.

Recently I was using [aTube Catcher](http://www.atube.me/) (Windows 10 64-bit), but unfortunately this software downloads tracks with some defects like:

1. In the middle of track gets cut 2-3 seconds (which the original track doesn't have) and this has happened a couple of times already.
2. Recently I have been downloading tracks being cutted by that software just a couple of seconds before completing any of the selected songs.

These defects completely ruin the experience, at least to me. I don't know if this happens to anyone else.

Would appreciate any suggestion as software to download youtube music as mp3. Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 2):

[YouTube DL](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/).

> youtube-dl is a command-line program to download videos from
>   YouTube.com and a few more [sites](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/supportedsites.html).

Download the executable, and place it in a folder. Then simply run  `youtube-dl -x` (from either Powershell or Command Prompt, at the directory) to download a video and extract its audio, then `avconv` to convert the audio to MP3.

Alternatively, you can use [FFMPeg](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) in conjunction with YouTubeDL to perform this.

- Free;
- Python based;
- Runs on Linux, Windows and can even use `pip` on Android

Comment: Runs on what OS? Where to find? Does it meet the requirements OP listed (avoiding the named issues)?

Comment: Agreed, with that rep, I would have expected a better answer

Comment: does that work for win10? seems like a linux command. I only use win10 for now, would appreciate some other recommendation.

Comment: Then you ought to have used the [tag:windows] tag. And either have used the [tag:gratis] tag or stated a budget. Take a look at [ask]. The more information that you give us, the better that we can help you, and not make unsuitable suggestions. Welcome aboard, Daniel. We look forward to helping you, and to you helping others :-)

Comment: I've edited the answer provided by @Kodio, and also suggested using FFMPeg to convert. Some shameless self-promotion, I made a basic post about it here: https://goo.gl/k5uiW7

Comment: @MichaelNancarrow accepting your "shameless self-promotion" due to your disclosure – but could you please use a link that's not obfuscated (i.e. the "real URL")? Some of us prefer not to be tracked more than really necessary :)

Comment: @Izzy Sure. TL;DR of the link - usage terms of YouTubeDL. Furthermore, can also enable bash via `Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux` and then `sudo apt-get install youtube-dl` ;)

Comment: @Izzy "Runs on what OS?" — They're cross-platform. "Does it meet the requirements OP listed (avoiding the named issues)?" — Yes, to my knowledge, these programs do not have the bugs listed in the original question. Surely that goes without saying.

Comment: @Kodiologist Michael already filled those gaps with his [edit], thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks @MichaelNancarrow , I'm taking a look on your website and your solution. I'm tempting to use Debian, Ubuntu or other Linux distribution since I have a notebook AMD dual core 1.3 GHZ plus 2GB ram DDR2. It's really frustrating to use with windows 10, can't even write on a notepad file and have to wait a couple of seconds until I can see what I'm writting on. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

There is a program called [JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/home/index) which works most of the time. You basically add the youtube video link and it offers you to download either the video in various quality settings or just the audio as an MP3.

However I noticed that this doesn't work for all videos. Some (especially really new releases) seem to be able prevent the attempt to download them.

Comment: JDownloader needs frequent updates because hosting services and video streaming services like YT keep changing APIs.

Answer (score 0):

[Freemake YouTube to MP3](http://www.freemake.com/free_youtube_converter/) is another good alternative.

Completely free, and does the job pretty well.

> Copy and paste YouTube links into Freemake to get audio. Or type song
>   or artist name, Freemake will find & convert YouTube music to MP3.
>   Convert YouTube multiple URLs extremely fast due to the multithread
>   download technology. You can search, download & play music at the same
>   time.

[image]

*Credits: Freemake.com*

Comment: Thanks man will take a look on it, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Sure! let me know if this works as you want

Comment: I tested it out already. No ads, fast, simple, looks great! My own complain pal would be that it doesn't have an option to select the quality for downloaded track. If would have so then may be the best choice for sure. Do you have any other tool recommended to download youtube as mp3? Thank you a lot.

Comment: When you search for music in Freemake, it automatically finds songs with the highest bitrate available, up to 320 kbps.